# How to configure python 3.7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python

I followed this tutorial (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/install-python-3-7-ubuntu-18-04/) to install python 3.7 on Ubuntu, why I cannot find the python3.7m folder in the path in /usr/include/?

It only contains the python3.6m folder in /usr/include/, which is a default python3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I think I successfully installed the python 3.7, because there is a python 3.7 folder in /usr/lib/

Comment: There isn't a folder called python3.7m or other python-related folders.

Comment: in terminal type python3.7 see if it working or not , if working then in bash change the alias for python3.7 to python3 , laternatively download anconda and you can setup multiple python environment there

Comment: I also installed anaconda. The message shows that: python3.7 
'Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
, but I need to fix the python3.7m in the usr/include/

Comment: When you type python in the terminal, is python3.7 running?

Comment: When I type python, it uses python3.7 of anaconda like /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [which](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/which.1.html) command to find where python is installed

```
which python3.7
```

It will be in `/usr/bin/python3.7m`

The `/usr/include/` folder contains the header files associated with the python development package. To get that you would have to install it first

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

Comment: Because you have installed it within the Anaconda environment. You can have multiple python installations on your system. To go to the default system installed one, you would have to deactivate anaconda.

Comment: Do you mean that if I install the python3.7 using that tutorial ((http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/install-python-3-7-ubuntu-18-04/), I have to type the command "conda deactivate"  before installing that. Then I will have a python3.7m folder in  /usr/include/, isn't it?

Comment: If you follow the tutorial without having a conda environment activated, you should end up with a folder in /user/bin/. If you are looking for the header files added in include, you would install python3.7-dev using sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev